# How to correctly use Nuxt / Vue ...mapMutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use `...mapMutations` with Vuex modules in Nuxt. My call to `this.setDates(dates)` results in an error:

> this.setDates is not a function

**In my Nuxt store: `store/header.js`**

```
export const mutations = {
    setDates(state, dates) {
        state.dates = dates;
    },
}
```

**In my component**

```
methods: {
    ...mapMutations(
        {'header': ['setDates']},
    ),
    changeDate(dates) {
        this.setDates(dates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will try to create a method called `header` using the mutation `setDates`:

```js
mapMutations(
  {'header': ['setDates']},
)
```

I believe what you want is:

```js
mapMutations('header', ['setDates'])
```

This will treat `header` as a namespace instead.

Answer (score 1):

You map your mutation as header, i think u need call header() instead of this.setDates()

from https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

```
...mapMutations({
      add: 'increment' // map `this.add()` to `this.$store.commit('increment')`
    })
```